# Adding CKEditor Library to SublimeCodeIntel Autocomplete

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, sublimetext2, sublimecodeintel

I've added the following to my `~/.codeintel/config` file but i can't get any autocomplete while writing plugins for CKEditor.

```
{
    "JavaScript": {
        "javascriptExtraPaths" : [
            "D:\libraries\ckeditor\ckeditor.js"
        ]
    }
}
```

Am I missing something, or it's just not doable? Perhaps I need to insert a comment in my CKEditor plugin file that it's using the CKEditor library?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting this instead:

```json
{
    "JavaScript": {
        "javascriptExtraPaths" : [
            "D:/libraries/ckeditor"
        ]
    }
}
```

using forward slashes `/` as path delimiters and just specifying the directory, instead of saying what file to look at.

Comment: @CincauHangus Have you tried deleting `~/.codeintel/db/javascript` to force reindexing?

Comment: Yes I have, and after that I created a new JS file and typed in CKEDITOR and it still says 'No available completion'.